# How to log when a relation already exist?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created a hierarchical tree to represent the organization chart of a company on Neo4j, which is like the picture below.

[image: Hierarchical Tree]

When I insert a lot of relation with a `LOAD CSV`, I use this request:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///newRelation.csv" AS row
MERGE (a:Person {name:row.person1Name})
MERGE(b:Person {name:row.person2Name})
FOREACH (t in CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS((a)-[*]->(b)) THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
    MERGE (a)-[pr:Manage]->(b) )
```

With this request, I only create the relationship if the two people do not already have a hierarchical relationship.

How to save (log) the list of relationships that are not created because the test below fail?

```
CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS((a)-[*]->(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the existence check to a level above the foreach:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///newRelation.csv" AS row
MERGE (a:Person {name:row.person1Name})
MERGE(b:Person {name:row.person2Name})
WITH a, b, row,
     CASE WHEN NOT exists((a)-[*]->(b)) THEN [1] ELSE [] END AS check
FOREACH (t IN check |
    MERGE (a)-[pr:Manage]->(b) 
)
WITH a, b, row, check WHERE size(check) = 0
RETURN a, b, row
```